# Can I write an if/else condition in a list comprehension? I have not been able to use any of what I've found

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to do an if/else with a list comprehension (I think).   I tried to follow a normal if  conditional format with the if/else at the end. I tried to  add 'num for num in nums'.  A few other things like the commented code at the bottom...but the best I can do is make res[] a list of 'None's.
I'm sure this will never be crucial and a normal if/else in a for loop works, it's just that I read Trey Hunner's visual take on List Comps and wondered about an else.

```
nums = [2,53,4,7,11,1]
print(nums)
res = []
for num in nums:
    if num <= 7:
        res.append("less")
    else:
        res.append("more")
print(res)

nums = [2,53,4,7,11,1]
print(nums) 
res = []      
res = [res.append("less") if num <= 7
        else res.append("more") 
        for num in nums
]
print(res)

# [a if tC else b for i in items if fC]
# [item
       for sublist in myList
       for item in (sublist if type(sublist) is list else sublist['val'])
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
["less" if num <= 7 else "more" for num in nums]
```

Your second chunk of code is broken: you call `res.append` inside the list comprehension.  Don't do that, you just need to produce individual values as I've done above.

Comment: Solved - Thank you John!